# how to take input using lambda function

Tags: python

how can we take input in lambda function?

```
z = lambda a,b,c,d : a+(b-c)*d
y = z(input("enter numbers: "))
print(y)
```

I expect input of the above expressions.

Comment: Just use a function, `lambda` is usually reserved for key functions and inline definitions

Comment: can you please resolve in my code.

Comment: You should get an error message that explains what you're doing wrong. You only pass it one string argument, but it gives this error: builtins.TypeError: <lambda>() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'b', 'c', and 'd'

Comment: A lambda *expression* defines a regular function, the same as a `def` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input` returns a string, you need to:

1. `split` it
2. cast each part to int using `map`
3. unpack it to different args [using `*` unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

try this:

```py
z = lambda a, b, c, d: a + (b - c) * d
y = z(*map(int,input("enter numbers: ").split()))
print(y)
```

example run:

```
enter numbers: 1 2 3 4
-3
```

Comment: The important point is there was nothing special about lambda. It's just that you have to pass the right arguments to call a function (defined or lambda).

Comment: @KennyOstrom yes, good clarification, `lambda` is just a shorthand way of defining a single-expression function.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example for one variable:

```
In [1]: z = lambda x : x+1                                                                                                                                                                     

In [2]: z(int(input()))                                                                                                                                                                        
4
Out[2]: 5

In [3]:
```

Answer (score 2):

That's neither readable nor flexible, but you can always embed a call to `input` in the lambda:

```
z = lambda: int(input('a:')) + int(input('b:'))
```

Comment: This doesn't allow you to recover from the `ValueError` that `int` will raise if the input isn't valid.

Answer (score 2):

`input` returns a string, so you'll need to convert that first:

```py
x = input('enter numbers: ') # 1 2 3 4

'1 2 3 4'

# use split
x = input('enter numbers: ')
x = [int(num) for num in x.split()]

# then unpack with the * syntax
c = lambda a, b, c, d: a+(b-c)*d

c(*x)
-3
```

Answer (score 1):

As rightly pointed out by Adam, the input function would get you a string. You can split the string and get the comma separated values and then convert them to integer like below

`z = lambda l : int(l[0])+(int(l[1])-int(l[2]))*int(l[3])
y = z(input("enter numbers: ").split(','))
print(y)`

An alternate way to achieve this would be:

`y = lambda stringFromTerminal : [int(eachString) for eachString in stringFromTerminal.split(',')]
x = y(input("enter numbers: "))
print(x[0]+(x[1]-x[2])*x[3])`